# How to get a script in init.d to execute on boot in Android?

Tags: android, linux, scripting

Part of my android app's functionality it to place a script I have written in init.d, so that it will be executed on every startup. (obviously my app is for root users only)

Here's what I am doing:

```
    busybox mount -o rw,remount /system"
    busybox cp -f /sdcard/*******/script /system/etc/init.d/script
    busybox chmod +x /etc/init.d/script
    update-rc.d script 99
```

The "update-rc.d script 99" line is where I run into trouble, it fails with an "update-rc.d not found" error.

Does anyone know what the proper command would be to make this work in Android??

I realize that this isn't exactly the most appropriate place to post this question, but I have come realize that this community is extremely knowledgeable on these matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add something like this to your `init.rc`

```
service script /system/etc/init.d/script
    oneshot
```

There's no `update-rc.d` in Android because there's no SYSV init either.