# Open html file from console

Tags: android, html, file

We've made a bash script that read plain data from a server and compose a html file. The file is created fine, and we just need to open it in a browser.

This task is more difficult than we have expected.

Could you please give us some advice about how to achieve it?

This if what we've done so far:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW http:///storage/sdcard0/path/final.html -t text/html
```

This code launches a dialog to select the browser, but it tries to locate the resource in internet. When we replace `http:///` by `file:///` the device tries to open the file with no luck.

We've read some others questions about this topic, but we're able to open the file directly from the browser. Our problem is how to open it from am.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Good question. I would write an app which opens the page with a tcp connection.

Comment: Of course, develop an app is an option, but was afraid to do it and later discover that a single line in the script could do the job :D. I think we commit a mistake when we supposed that open a local file whith a browser is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me put in a plug for [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for getting and parsing existing HTML and for creating new HTML... just has a bunch to offer.

Second, you'll want to use `loadDataWithBaseUrl` from the WebView class like so:

`webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", thingToLoadAsHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank")`

where thingToLoadAsHtml is a String with all the HTML in it.

See the [android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for more info.

Comment: yes, but we're not working with java. We just have a bash script and we want to launch a web browser and open this local html file.

Comment: Huh... interesting. What would invoke the script to run in the first place?

Comment: by now, we run it manually from a cosole, but when finished we will run it as a service, adding it to the init.rc file, as this SO explains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464713/how-to-get-a-script-in-init-d-to-execute-on-boot-in-android