# howto enable android tether on boot with init.d script

Tags: android, boot, init.d

i'm having trouble running firewall rules on boot through init.d
My current syntax is

21tether

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

iptables -t nat -A natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o rmnet0 -j MASQUERADE

enable from terminal works fine :S, thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Trouble, what trouble?

Comment: it just doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

[This answer may help you better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464713/how-to-get-a-script-in-init-d-to-execute-on-boot-in-android), although for me it didn't work, probably because of some missing parameters.

If you succeeded please post the solution.